# Different Chrome checkbox size

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I would like to resolve, in some elegant way, a design problem which only happens in Chrome.
When I wrap “input” type checkbox with `div` which has bootstrap class `col-…`. This `div` div is filled by checkbox, but in Chrome the checkbox also changes size (gets bigger)
I found a solution, which basically resolves problem, but is not ideal.

```
 @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
       [class*="col-"] input[type=checkbox] {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.5) !important;
        }
    }
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Pmilan/2cm7vn9s/)

Firstly, I need to make this rule for Chrome only,  because according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-webkit-device-pixel-ratio) this not best practice.
Secondly, the change of scale not only affects the size of the check box, but also everything within the div. Due to that, I lose the feature, that customer must not click exactly into the check-box to get it checked.
Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your problem is that in your code presented in the JSFiddle, you are using `form-control` class which has fixed height. Regarding FF and Chrome behaviour, it seems that only Chrome actually lets you to set the dimensions of checkbox using CSS...

I recommend you to check the Bootstrap [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) and see how the checkbox is implemented in Bootstrap.

Comment: Some of the classes, attributes etc. are included because this website is developed in ASP.NET MVC resp. Razor. I think you are solving a slightly different problem.
I want to create a “box” around the checker, that makes it same size (like in in firefox) in all browsers.

Comment: The point is to make a responsive form optimized for PC and tablets. My idea is that, when you are using it from a cellphone or tablet (or some other device with small screen) and want to check the box, which will be small and easy to miss  in this scenario there will be a slightly larger invisible “box” that will check the checker even though you actually miss the visible element.
I want to avoid this solution as I have the label and in my opinion it is not ideal.
[Like this](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#checkboxes-and-radios-without-lab)

Comment: Well I don't know Razore nor ASP.NET MVC, but I am pretty sure that there is some way to override the default behaviour, which might be needed to do.

Comment: Regarding your idea, I am not sure if this kind of optimisation is really necessary as I think it is pretty easy to hit checkbox on mobile device (just tried it). But if you really need to do it, then you have to use the same approach as in the docs you mentioned. You have to wrap the checkbox with `label` element (or use `for` attribute) and style the label. I think it is pretty bad idea to style directly the checkbox in this manner...